# How to make an object on canvas moving left and right to the x-axis smoothly on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on a simple game called "catch the falling objects". On the desktop devices the game is working fine and smooth. The "space rocket" (use the following link to see the game) is moving on the x-axis smooth when you are pressing the keys left and right. On mobile devices now, I'm having a small issue.When you press on the left side or right side of the "space rocket" is moving fine. But when you press and hold the "rocket" is not moving moving on the direction that you keep pressing on the screen. If you release your hand you will see that the rocket "jumped" from the one position to the other, and doesn't have the same smoothly movement like on the desktop. I did the following code but is not working properly

UPDATE 2

```
var mc = new Hammer(htmlCanvas);
mc.add(new Hammer.Press({ event: 'press', time:1 }));
mc.on("press", function(ev) {
    console.log("dsaDS");
    touchDown = true;
setInterval(function(){
   while(touchDown) { 
        console.log("down");
            if (ev.center.x < player.x)
            {
                player.x -=  Math.floor(CANVAS_WIDTH / player.width);
            }
            else
            {
                player.x += Math.floor(CANVAS_WIDTH / player.width);
            }

            if (ev.center.x == player.x)
            {
                touchDown = false;
            }

    } }, 1000);
});

mc.on("pressup", function(ev) {
    touchDown = false;
    console.log("up");
});
```

Can anyone suggest a better solution? Here is the link of the game
[Game](https://testing.gpanayi.com/) and here is the full code of my game [code](http://pastebin.com/dhaBkNqY)

UPDATE 1: It is not working on any device, iOS and Android

UPDATE 2: I have changed the way that I'm detecting the press on the screen

Comment: This is a well written question, but there is still details missing; Which mobile devices? IOS? Android? Which versions? What browsers?

Comment: Based on nothing more than a guess, I´d reckon the problem is `while(touchdown)`, keeping the particular thread (or however it's implemented in the device) too busy to update the screen. Could you put the move in an `setInterval` (with a small interval) , that is started on touchdown and stopped on touchup?

Comment: You should not be doing your game logic inside your event handlers. IO event handlers are for registering IO events, Events can come in at any speed and any quantity (touch events come in at huge rates that is why your player jumps). just flag that the touch is down and where, then in the main loop use that information to update your player, that way you can control how and when the player moves. It does not matter if you miss events

Comment: JarrodRoberson I forgot to mention it, sorry about that. I have tested it on iPhone 6s (chrome, safari) and Galaxy J7 (chrome). Me.Name and Blindman67 I used your advice but still is not working. Something I'm doing wrong. I have updated the code http://pastebin.com/dhaBkNqY, the new section is on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Me.Name and @Blindman67 I came with a solution which is the following

```
function move(touchDown)
{
     if(touchDown)
     {
       touchMoves =  setTimeout(function(){
            if (Math.floor(touchX) < Math.floor(player.x + player.width))
            {
                if ((Math.floor(player.x + player.width) - Math.floor(touchX)) <= 10 )
                {
                    touchDown = false;
                    clearTimeout(touchMoves);
                }
                else
                {
                   player.x -=  Math.floor(CANVAS_WIDTH / player.width); 
                }

            }
            else if ((Math.floor(touchX) == Math.floor(player.x + player.width)) || (player.x == (CANVAS_WIDTH - player.width)))
            {

                touchDown = false;
                clearTimeout(touchMoves);
            }
            else
            {
                if ((Math.floor(touchX) - Math.floor(player.x + player.width)) <= 10 )
                {
                    touchDown = false;
                    clearTimeout(touchMoves);
                }
                else
                {
                   player.x +=  Math.floor(CANVAS_WIDTH / player.width); 
                }
            }

            if (touchDown)
            {
                move(touchDown);  
            }

        }, 100);
     }
}
mc.on("press", function(ev) {
    if (gameIsActive)
    {
        touchDown = true;
        touchX = ev.center.x;
        move(touchDown);
   }

});

mc.on("pressup", function(ev) {
    if (gameIsActive)
    {
        touchDown = false;
    }
});
```